# Latest posts from multiple post types in one single loop?

Tags: wordpress

As the title says. Is there any way to get the latest posts from multiple post types in one single loop? Without using wpdb if at all possible?

Comment: May be try rss aggregator widget: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/

Comment: Coded sorry, no plugins. Just curious before I use a custom query if there is a way. It must be a fairly common requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using `WP_Query()`, you can choose an array of post types. Here is an (untested) example:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'custom-post-type'),
    'posts_per_page => 3
);
?>
```

[More info on `WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: Yes but to select say the first 2 of each post type I was wondering.